# Slide Dialog from behind a table

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a table with several rows, on the last column I added a button that display a dialog. What I want to do is to slide to the right the dialog from behind the table, but because the dialog gets append to the body this being `z-index:0`, I cant. The only thing I can do is have the dialog `z-index:-1` and then `z-index:0`, but it does not give the illusion of sliding, it just appears.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd think that you could wrap your table and dialog in a div and give the div relative positioning. The give the table and dialog absolute positioning with the table having a higher z-index than the dialog. Position the table over the dialog and don't hide the dialog. Then just animate the dialog as needed (making sure the container div is wide enough to handle it).

Comment: The thing is that the Dialog div is attached to the body and the table its inside the div container, several divs nested, how can I wrap the Dialog div with the table? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I re-append the Dialog from the body to the container where the table is, I have the Dialog div as a sibling of the table; I have the table as z-index:3 and I change the Dialog to z-index:2 but the Dialog still over the table. any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: I got it!! I just need it to change the table to  position: relative. and it work. Thanks!!